# Using OpenCV in Xamarin.iOS (arm64)

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, xamarin.ios, opencv3.0

I've been struggling for a while now to get OpenCV to run on Xamarin.iOS with arm64. The latest version I could find on opencv.org don't seem to be built for arm64. I had trouble building the latest libraries myself, but got the build going for OpenCV 2.4.12 (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4.12). However, when I add the library to my solution (via a binding library), I get the following error:

```
MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_free_large. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_free_small. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_get_large. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_get_small. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_mem_available. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_mem_init. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_mem_term. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _jpeg_open_backing_store. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
    MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

I've read on https://github.com/twelve17/openalpr-ios/issues/5 that I needed to link to libjpeg. I do this by using the following mtouch command: 
`-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -ljpeg -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libjpeg.a"`
Now however, I get the error that duplicates are available:

```
MTOUCH:  duplicate symbol _jpeg_std_error in: 
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_CreateCompress'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_destroy_compress'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_abort_compress'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_suppress_tables'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_finish_compress'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_marker'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_m_header'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_m_byte'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_tables'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapimin.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_start_compress'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_scanlines'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_write_raw_data'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcapistd.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_c_coef_controller'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jccoefct.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jccoefct.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_color_converter'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jccolor.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jccolor.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_forward_dct'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcdctmgr.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcdctmgr.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_make_c_derived_tbl'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_gen_optimal_table'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_huff_encoder'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jchuff.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_compress_master'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcinit.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcinit.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_c_main_controller'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcmainct.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcmainct.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_marker_writer'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcmarker.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcmarker.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jinit_c_master_control'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcmaster.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcmaster.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_abort'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_destroy'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_alloc_quant_table'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_alloc_huff_table'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcomapi.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_add_quant_table'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_set_linear_quality'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_quality_scaling'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_set_quality'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_set_defaults'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_default_colorspace'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_set_colorspace'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5212: Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_jpeg_simple_progression'.
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/opencv2.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5213: Duplicate symbol in: /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a(jcparam.o) (Location related to previous error)
    MTOUCH: error MT5201: Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -L/Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS -ljpeg -force_load /Users/Alexander/Projects/VRMouse/iOS/libjpeg.a
    MTOUCH: error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

`3 Warning(s)
 105 Error(s)`

I've no idea how to solve this and where I'm going wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not sure, but if I recall you don't need the `-ljpeg` flag along with `${ProjectDir}/libjpeg.a`. (But I am not sure, its been a while since I compiled opencv for ios. )

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It gave me the feeling I was doing something wrong with the built and allowed me to find a workaround.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working, and good job answering your own question so future users can benefit! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments I received from Chris Britt I got the feeling something went wrong with the built of OpenCV. I managed to find a pre-built version of the framework for iOS. SDK 7.1, armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386, x86_64 (https://github.com/AlexeyIS/OpenCV-iOS). Even though it does not explain what I was doing wrong, it is a nice workaround that allows me to run OpenCV on arm64.